# Why would Microsoft Word be suddenly unable to open network files with spaces in them?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

We use a program called Titlesoft on our Windows 2008 server that accesses stored network files. Until this week files would open just fine in the program.

Now when we try to open the files, Word (Office 365) gives an error message (let's pretend the filename is `123-123 File Commitment`) that it can't open file `W:\BLAH\BLAH\123-123` and then when I close off that error, another pops up saying it couldn't open file `W:\BLAH\BLAH\File` and then finally another that says it couldn't open file `W:\BLAH\BLAH\Commitment.doc` so clearly it thinks the document is 3 different documents because of the spaces.

If I remove the spaces, the file will open just fine. Is there anything in Windows or Word that might cause this behavior?

Comment: Review what has changed since the last time it worked.  Windows Update on the PC or server, Titlesoft update, Word update.  It looks like spaces are not being used consistently, although it's hard to tell where it's broken in the process without diving in.  Escape characters like spaces used to give me problems when writing BAT scripts, but then I stopped using spaces in files names.  If Titlesoft has updated, perhaps you can revert that update.  Perhaps also send an email to the Titlesoft developer so that they know there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main issue is we don't have support with Titlesoft anymore and they charge a ridiculous amount for any amount of support out of contract. I will try and investigate if anything might have changed. Supposedly nothing is supposed to change with Titlesoft since we don't get updates anymore.

Comment: Is there a command-line option for opening a file though Titlesoft? If so, put the full file path in double quotes, e.g. "W:\BLAH\BLAH\123-123\Filenm W Space.doc".